# \hangindent and \hsize

Tags: parshape

Refer from TeXbyTopic sec 18.3.5  *Hanging indentation versus `\leftskip` shifting*

> Setting \leftskip to some positive value for a paragraph means that the \hsize stays
> the same, but every line starts with a glue item. Hanging indentation, on the other hand,
> is implemented by **decreasing the \hsize** value for the lines that hang, and shifting the
> finished horizontal boxes horizontally in the surrounding vertical list

But following example does not show the changes on `\hsize`

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\hsize=300pt
\parindent=0pt
\hangindent=2cm
\the\hsize\\\the\hsize

\the\hsize\\\the\hsize
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `\hsize` is changed during the process that splits a paragraph into lines, not at the user level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The description in “TeX by Topic” could indeed be misleading.

What happens is that a (primitive) `\par` command will send the whole paragraph to the internal processor where it will be split into lines according to the values of the relevant parameters *when `\par` has been executed.

There will always be a *single* value of `\hsize` for a paragraph. However, when `\hangindent` is nonzero, the value of `\hsize` will be modified during the internal operation for the lines where hanging indentation is specified by `\hangafter`.

Such changes only happen in the internal processor and are not available at the user level.